# reducer switch statements not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, reducers

I've just started out with Redux and trying to implement a simple MERN App (for practice). 
Everything in my code is working fine, but my reducer function is showing unexpected behaviour. When an action (which gets fetches data from express api) is called my reducer correctly goes to the particular switch case data logs successfully but then three times the default case is passed and data on my component which I log is showing null. Please Help.
Here's my code:-

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import articlesReducer from './store/reducers/articlesReducer';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    articles: articlesReducer
});
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**articles.js**

```
export const getAllArticles = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        return (
            fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/articles')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    dispatch({type: 'GET_ALL_ARTICLES', articles: data})
                })
        );
    };
};
```

**articlesReducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
    articles:null
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_ALL_ARTICLES':
            console.log('in reducer', action.type, action.articles[0]);
            return {
                ...state,
                articles: action.articles
            };
        default:
            console.log('In default');
            return state;
    }
};
export default reducer;
```

**myComponent**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAllArticles } from '../../store/actions/articles.js';

class MainPage extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.initArticles();
        console.log(this.props.articles);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <br />
                <h1>Here comes the articles!!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        articles: state.articles
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        initArticles: () => dispatch(getAllArticles())
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage);
```

The output in my console is somewhat like this:-

```
In default
In default
In default
{articles: null}
in reducer GET_ALL_ARTICLES {articles[0] Object}
```

I don't know what is the mistake. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: There's way too much code, can you try and isolate the buggy behavior, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but myself don't know where is the bug coming from it's mainly related to my reducer part and I guess in my component (not sure though), actions.js perfectly sends the data to the reducer.

Comment: I really understand that code is quite big. But if you really see they just small snippets and clearly understandable. I would really appreciate if you could give it a try.

Comment: I think your articles are into `state.articles.articles`. The first one because it's in the articles reducer, the second, into the articles reducer, it's the articles field.

Comment: The data in my reducer reaches properly but not to the component and the three times "In default" in the output on console.

Comment: @Ursus, I tried that also, but then it shows a `null` instead of `{articles: null}` in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is actually the problem but you incorrectly access the `articles`. You have a root reducer with `articles` reducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    articles: articlesReducer
});
```

which initial state is:

```
const initialState = {
    articles:null
};
```

And in your mapDispatchToProps you "import" whole reducer state:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        articles: state.articles
    };
};
```

I think you wanted to access `articles` property

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        articles: state.articles.articles
    };
};
```

Other than that everything seems to be fine. I would however as pointed in comment initialize `articles` as empty array `[]`.

```
const initialState = {
    articles: []
};
```

Comment: yeah, also better to put `const initialState = [];`

Comment: @Tomasz Mularczyk I tried everything now I get an error that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'articles' of undefined` at `articles: state.articles.articles`

Comment: Also, I don't understand that why I get three `In default` and then a correct/expected output of `in reducer ....`

Comment: Hey, back with a little update after the changes you mentioned... I am getting my data in the `componentWillReceiveProps()` and the `render()` method. And, thus I can display it on my page. Thanks a ton!! @Tomasz Mularczyk :-) Sorry if I took a lot your time